# What is the best way to split a series of recessed ceiling lights to two switches?

Tags: wiring, lighting, switch, light

I have a large basement with 10 can lights in the ceiling controlled by a single pull switch at the bottom of the stairs. I have framed in a bedroom that essentially cuts the area in half with 6 of the 10 lights being inside the new room. I wish to keep 4 on the original switch while bypassing the series with a switch inside the bedroom to control the 6 bedroom cans.

Is there a way to do so using the existing wiring? Or am I stuck running all new wire to some or all of the lights?

Comment: Have you put up the drywall yet?

Comment: Is there another place in the bedroom you can tap an always-hot from?

Comment: No drywall yet. And yes, I have access to an always hot

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the feed from the series of lights. At that point you can bring hot from an outlet to a switch, then up to the string you removed the feed from. Make sure to take the switched hot neutral and ground to the string--you don't want either the hot or neutral from the original feed connected to the now bedroom lights.

Comment: To help clarify, just remove the cable that runs between the two groups. Replace it with a longer cable that runs from the now-isolated group to the switch.